# jQuery Mobile odd URL in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, internet-explorer-8

When switching pages on IE8 the target URL is different than other browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, and even IE10. For example:
From jqm's own website:

```
http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/
```

When clicking on one of the widget section items, Accordion for example, the URL is properly modified on Chrome, Firefox, and IE10:

```
http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/accordions/
```

But on IE8 the URL becomes:

```
http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/#/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/accordions/
```

So far I haven't really noticed any different functional behavior. Is this a jqm bug or expected behavior? I'm concerned that this may cause some issues down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becouse Internet Explorer 8-9 (and older) doesn't support **HTML5 History API**

http://caniuse.com/#feat=history

**More exmample info :** https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/#how-would-they-look-in-a-html4-browser